# OpenLayers 4 getGetFeatureInfoUrl and HitTollerance

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using this piece of code

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {

...
url = pmfeatlayer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coordinate, viewResolution, projection, {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});

if (url) {...
}
...
}
```

And here my layer:

```
pmfeatlayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  extent: ext,
  preload: Infinity,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: Settings.url,
    params: {'LAYERS': sQLayers, MYORDERS: Settings.order, DTO: DTo, format: 'image/png'},
    ratio: 1.1,
    gutter: 40
  })
});
```

to get the feature info on `pmfeatlayer`, Inside all the code I have also a function that displays a list of the feature in that pixel (If I have more than 1 URL create a list of them)

How can I increase the tolerance?

I found this example but I can't get it work, is this just for features or also for layers?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/hit-tolerance.html

Here a screenshot of my map.

[image]

I have a `map layer` and a `featlayers` (all the street restriction are on that layer) and as you can see from the popup at that pixel I have 2 restrictions, how can I increase the radius o get also the 2 street sign for example (because at the moment he display the 2 street line but not the signs)?

Comment: I can't see from your code if you have both layers listed in INFO_LAYERS parameter in the GetFeatureInfo request that gets generated.

Comment: all the data you see is on the INFO_LAYERS, and then there is the MAP_LAYER but it's just for the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I make it works with `FEATURE_COUNT:10`,`buffer` doesn't work.

Checking the Request WMS URL I found `FEATURE_COUNT:10`, in another version of the project with others type of data, a parameter that is not present in the old code, I'm still unable to understand how OL2 has inserted this parameter in the URL

Answer (score 1):

WMS getFeatureInfo sends a single XY coordinate. The receiving server could apply a buffer. For GeoServer, you can use the [`buffer`](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) vendor specific paramter

```
url = pmfeatlayer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coordinate, 
         viewResolution, 
         projection, 
         {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html','buffer':'10'}
      );
```

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work, I'm using MapServer, is possible to do something about it in MapServer?

Comment: @Sebastiano It seems to be [layer's](http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html) TOLERANCE and TOLERANCEUNITS

Comment: I've already tried to increase the TOLERANCE in the MAP file but nothing changes, I'm able to have back the data even if I'm not on top of the data but I don't have more data, I have the same amount of data

Comment: I also found some difference between the parameters sent to MapServer between OL2 and OL4 but some of them I don't know how they are created like `FEATURE_COUNT:10`

Comment: at the end I make it works with `FEATURE_COUNT:10`, `buffer` doesn't work. I'm still unable to understand how OL2 has inserted this parameter in the URL